# Visual Studio locks on directories isn't released

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, locking, git-bash

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, but this has been a problem in previous versions and with other Operating Systems.

Visual Studio is keeping it's lock on directories, even when the solution is closed.

Even after closing Visual Studio, directories are *still* locked.

1. What process is locking these directories?
2. How can I stop it?

Comment: Are you simply closing the solution, or opening a different one from a different path?  The "current working directory" probably does not change just from closing.

Comment: Closed the solution, and closed Visual Studio.  Good point that it the working directory might not change from closing (it should though), but I'd hope it released the lock when closing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this on in case anyone else is making this mistake.  The Git Bash console locks the directory it is in (if it's a git directory).

Close the Git Bash and suddenly, lock gone.